# Create a Load test, where similar load is coming every 10 min at 10k rps

Tags: scala, gatling

I need to write gatling script I need to generate similar load for every 10 min holding this for 2 hrs for 10k rps

Is it possibile to write such scenario in Gatling, Since I am new to scala and gatling

scenario.repeat( 20 ).feed (load.csv). exec(  ).maxDuration(2 hours)

I see load the is not repeating with such traffic pattern

Answer (score 0):

you can use forever() instead of repeat() in combination with maxDuration and achieve the load by controlling the virtual users count.

```
   ScenarioBuilder downloadFileScn = scenario("Download file")
            .forever()
            .on(exec(downloadFileRequest).pause(Duration.ofSeconds(THINK_TIME)));
```

```
        setUp(
                downloadFileScn.injectClosed(constantConcurrentUsers(WORKERS).during(Duration.ofSeconds(RAMP_UP))))
                .protocols(httpProtocol)
                .maxDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(DURATION));
    }
```

When using repeat(), maxDuration() does not really help.

Comment: I tried unfortunately it didn't work, giving me steep load 
I am looking for the load pattern of the sign graph, where the suppose max duration of 60 min, (every 5 min I see traffic and 5 min no traffic) which is 10 min and 6 such traffic patterns in 60 min

Comment: ScenarioBuilder downloadFileScn = scenario("Download file")
            .forever()
            .on(exec(downloadFileRequest).pause(Duration.ofSeconds( 10 min )));

     setUp(
                downloadFileScn.injectClosed(constantConcurrentUsers(WORKERS).during(Duration.ofSeconds(10 min ))))
                .protocols(httpProtocol)
                .maxDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(60 min));
    }

Comment: You have added pause of 10 mins thats why. The code I provided is stripped a bit.